# Changing CSS for mobile devices with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, mobile

I've encountered a bit of a confusing challenge with CSS/Javascript. I'm making a simple page, and I want the layout to be different for mobile users. However, I can't seem to change the size of input forms.

If the user's on mobile, I have the following Javascript run:

```
document.getElementById("bookimage").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("inputs").style.width="140px";
```

So it hides an image, and should reduce the width of my input boxes to 140px. Unfortunately, while it successfully hides the image, the input fields are unchanged.

I took the code outside the if statement so that it applies to any device, and on my desktop the inputs are properly resized. I also tried setting it to style.display="none", which again works for desktop but does nothing on mobile. I then cleared my phone's cache, but no change. Even when I set the width directly in the CSS styles section it has no effect on what the phone displays. (I'm using a Samsung running Android if that's relevant.)

I can't fathom why everything works but this one particular function. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some code examples of what you have?

Comment: Ah, it seems to have been caused by a document.getElementById("container").style.padding="0px"; line that came before. Removing it seems to have it all working fine now.